# Sort users based on initials with Java Stream API. If initials repeat, sort based on user's age. Both of them are sorted in descending order

Tags: java, list, sorting, java-stream, comparator

I am trying to sort users based on their initials, and when initials are repeated, say 'Alex Fay' and 'Alba Finn', I have to sort them based on their age in descending order.

This is my current code:

```
List<SortedUser> sortedUserList = list.stream()
        .sorted((a, b) -> {
             int first = a.getName().charAt(0) + a.getLastName().charAt(0);
             int second = b.getName().charAt(0) + b.getLastName().charAt(0);
             if(first > second) {
                  return -1;
             } if(first < second) {
                   return 1;
             }

             return b.getAge() - a.getAge();
           }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The problem with this code is that when I have initials 'AR' and 'EN', their sums are the same (`147`) - therefore *`first == second`*, and they appear one after the other in incorrect order.
I also tried to compare the first name initial and the last name initial separately, but I still couldn't get it to work.

What can I change in order to sort them the way I want it?

**Sample input:**

```
(name=Alexandre, lastName=Wuckert, age=66),
(name=Allan, lastName=Wehner, age=84),
(name=Bradley, lastName=Thompson, age=78),
(name=Bernice, lastName=Schoen, age=63)
```

**Sample output:**

```
(name=Bradley, lastName=Thompson, age=78),
(name=Bernice, lastName=Schoen, age=63),
(name=Allan, lastName=Wehner, age=84),
(name=Alexandre, lastName=Wuckert, age=66)
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding characters to sort on is unreliable since many pairs can sum to the same value.  So you should build a String of initials rather than add them. Then use the following in your sort method.

```
String first = a.getName().charAt(0) + "" + a.getLastName().charAt(0);
String second = b.getName().charAt(0) +"" + b.getLastName().charAt(0);
int result = first.compareTo(second);
    
return result > 0 ? -1 : result < 0 ? 1 : b.getAge-a.getAge();
```

The above will sort in descending order based on the initials.  If result == 0 then the ages will be used (as you did before).

**Note:**  you could also do `second.compareTo(first)` and then either swap `1 and -1` or swap the `inequality signs`.  Which ever makes more sense to you.

Here are some other alternatives for your consideration. I used a record to hold the User data.

```
record User(String getName, String getLastName, int getAge) {
}

List<User> list =
        new ArrayList<>(List.of(new User("Alexandre", "Wuckert", 66),
                new User("Allan", "Wehner", 84),
                new User("Bradley", "Thompson", 78),
                new User("Bernice", "Schoen", 63)));
```

- stream the list of users.
- You can create a String comparator and then apply it to the `sort` method

```
Comparator<User> compUsers = Comparator
        .comparing((User u) -> u.getName().charAt(0) + ""
                + u.getLastName().charAt(0))
        .thenComparing(User::getAge).reversed();
```

- first compare the initials
- if the initials are equal, then compare on the user's age.
- reversed() reverses are previous comparators to change from ascending (default) to descending.

```
List<User> sortedUsers = list.stream().sorted(compUsers).toList();

sortedUsers.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
User[getName=Bradley, getLastName=Thompson, getAge=78]
User[getName=Bernice, getLastName=Schoen, getAge=63]
User[getName=Allan, getLastName=Wehner, getAge=84]
User[getName=Alexandre, getLastName=Wuckert, getAge=66]
```

Note that you could also just sort the list in place and not use `streams` as long as the list is mutable. Here the previously defined `Comparator` is used.

```
list.sort(compUsers);
```

Note: It is also possible to put the Comparator code directly into the `sort` method.  But defining it separately lends itself to reuse and can make the stream construct less cluttered.

Answer (score 1):

To make the code more readable and less error-prone, use Java 8 static methods of the `Comparator` interface instead of placing a chain of conditions into a lambda expression.

Here's another way of implementing a *comparator* that will compare *users* based on the first letter of the first name, then by the first letter of the last name and finally by age in descending order:

```
Comparator<SortedUser> byFirstLettersAndAgeReversed =
    Comparator.comparingInt((SortedUser user) -> user.getFirstName().charAt(0))
        .thenComparingInt(user -> user.getLastName().charAt(0))
        .thenComparingInt(SortedUser::getAge).reversed();


 List<SortedUser> sortedUserList = list.stream()
    .sorted(byFirstLettersAndAgeReversed)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can define a couple of comparators as `public static` fields inside the user class and reuse them, when you need to sort or compare these objects in a specific way.